If $G$ is a finite group of order $|G|=936$, then there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $|H|=117$
I'm very confuse with this exercise. The prime number decomposition of $|G|$ is $936=2^{3}3^{2}13$. That is, $G$ is not a $p$-group, has no order $pq$, $p^2q$, $p^mq$ or $p^mq^n$. And $|H|=117=3^{2}13$ is not a prime or power of prime. And $G$ is not a cyclic group. In other words, it seems to me that $G$ and $H$ do not fit any of the conditions and consequences of Sylow's theorems and their corollaries. Any tips on what to do? Is there a theorem that fits these conditions that I have missed?

By the Sylow Theorems, the number of $13$-Sylow subgroups must divide $|G|$ and be congruent to $1$ modulo $13$. So it is a divisor of $2^3\times 3^2$ that is congruent to $1$ modulo $13$.
You have possible values $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $3$, $6$, $12$, $24$, $9$, $18$, $36$, and $72$. Of these, the only one that is congruent to $1$ modulo $13$ is $1$. So $G$ has a unique, hence normal, subgroup of order $13$, $P$.
Since $P$ is normal, for every subgroup $K$ of $G$, we have $KP=PK$, hence $KP$ is always a subgroup of $G$. The order is $|KP| = |K||P|/|K\cap P|$. Since $|P|=13$, all you need is a subgroup of order $9$. Does $G$ have a subgroup of order $9$?

I don't know if G has a subgroup of order 9, but it does have Sylow subgroups of order 3. So can I apply this argument recursively to prove that there must be a subgroup of order 9?

Hint: the 3-Sylow subgroups are not order 3. Take another look at the definitions.

@ArturCruvinelMontibeller You seem to have a mistaken definition of Sylow subgroup.

@ArturoMagidin Yes it is true. I got confused. Sorry.

The sylow p-subgroup of a group of order $p^{\alpha}m$ where $p$ does not divide $m$ is a subgroup of order $p^{\alpha}$. Hence, there will be a subgroup of order $9$.

The Sylow $13$ subgroup is normal,  because the number of them is $1\pmod {13}$ and divides $72.$  Then just note that $14,40,53,66\not \mid72.$
Thus we have the group $G/S_{13},$ of order $72.$
By Sylow again,  this group has a (Sylow) subgroup $H$ of order $9.$  It's index is $8.$
Finally by the correspondence theorem $H$ corresponds to a subgroup of $G$ containing $S_{13},$ of index $8.$
